# ¿Como cerrar esta ventana modal?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

tengo un problema para cerrar una ventana modal de la siguiente pagina
https://www.lojasrenner.com.br/c/feminino/bermudas-e-shorts/-/N-comsxxZ1hwylc0/p1

probe de esta manera:

1)

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="btClose"]').click()
```

2)

```
browser.execute_script('document.querySelector("#btClose").click()')
```

el modal esta dentro del iframe siguiente, en el mismo tiene < head> y < body> y dentro del body está, creo, la forma de cerrarlo, que seria el boton de close **"< a href="" id="btClose" >< /a>"**

```
<iframe frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no" 
width="1" height="1" src="https://lojasrenner.soclminer.com.br/7462de67032e4fbbbc52b7245c0fc85e/index.min.html?appId=463125217038882&amp;id=a37eadddbcc34b51b27babb866372869&amp;name=Lojas%20Renner&amp;pluginId=7462de67032e4fbbbc52b7245c0fc85e&amp;version=20190702165223000000&amp;dns=lojasrenner&amp;url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.lojasrenner.com.br%2Fc%2Ffeminino%2F-%2FN-4zo6za%2Fp1&amp;path=https%3A%2F%2Flojasrenner.soclminer.com.br%2F7462de67032e4fbbbc52b7245c0fc85e%2F&amp;hasOptIn=false&amp;isMobile=false&amp;gaEnabled=false&amp;googleApp=2" 
id="social-push" class="socl-iframe" name="social-push">
<head></head>
<body>
<div class="plg"><a href="" id="btClose"></a><a href="" id="btGo" class="btn"></a> 
<img id="imgDesk" src="https://lojasrenner.soclminer.com.br/7462de67032e4fbbbc52b7245c0fc85e/image.png?v=636976831423743367" alt=""><img id="imgMobi" src="https://lojasrenner.soclminer.com.br/7462de67032e4fbbbc52b7245c0fc85e/image.png?v=636976831423743367" alt=""></div></body>
</iframe>
```

*pd: no copié todo el iframe, solo una parte*

otra forma que intenté fue:

```
browser.switch_to_alert()
```

pero también falla.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si el boton está dentro del iframe primero debes cambiar al iframe con:

```
browser.switch_to.frame("social-push")
```

Despues interactuar con el boton:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="btClose"]').click()
```

Y para terminar volver al contexto general, del que saliste al cambiar de frame:

```
browser.switch_to.default_content()
```